# Excel Formula to Calculate Checkin Time

Tags: excel

I have a file from restaurant log of 1 month. I need to calculate the `Checkin Time` time from `Time` and `Bill Number` column.

**My Format is:**

```
Date |Time| TableNumber| Checkin time |Bill Number ..|...|...|
```

I can calculate it manually one at a time by copying the 1st data of `Time` column and copying in `Checkin time` where bill number is same.

I have attached a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm7JF.png) of the data.

**Example 1: Blue square**

Here in the blue square we can see that first value of `Time` column  is `0:02:37` and I have pasted it in `Checkin time` which has `Bill Number` 29 .

**Example 2: Red square**

First value of `Time` is `16:08:40` And I have pasted in `Checkin time` column which have bill number of `1` and so on..

I did it manually without any equation or formulas. But the problem is the data is of 1 month and I have about 6 to be calculated.

**What I tried**
From the formula given to me by @girlvsdata
I tried

```html
=MINIFS(B:B,E:E,E3)
```

I did get the data for 1st two unique Bill numbers, but after dragging down the forumla further down, I get different Time for new bill number. + as the bill number repeats in further down rows many times, it gives me same time of 1st bill number for repeated bill numbers.
Here is the screenshot of after What I tried 
[Screenshot_after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzW7M.png)

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @girlvsdata Version 1806(Build 10228.20134) .

Comment: Is that in Office 365?

Comment: @girlvsdata Yes.I checked it from File> Account tab.

Comment: Do you mean the checkin time is not correct for row 55 and that it should be 18:47:26?

Comment: @Jerry Yes. Exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose the following:

```
=IF(AND(E3=E1,C3=C1,A3=A1),D1,MIN(OFFSET(E3,0,-3,MATCH(0,(E3:E$18=E3)*(C3:C$18=C3)*(A3:A$18=A3),0)-1,1)))
```

It is a bit long and will likely take a while to calculate if you have lots of rows. The above formula is to be entered as an array formula, i.e. copy/type the formula then instead of pressing Enter, use Ctrl+Shift+Enter. If you do it right, excel will insert `{}` around it like in the screen shot below:

[image]

Change the ranges `E3:E$18`, `C3:C$18` and `A3:A$18` accordingly and notice that they are all one row **below** the end of the table (otherwise you get `#N/A` for the last bill).

Comment: This doesn't do what OP wanted I'm afraid. Bill 1 in row 10 should display checkin 18:15:28. Or what am I missing here?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However this doesnt worked too. It gives #REF! in many cells. Since the Table number is not unique and it repeats over and over again, data is same for every number. :(

Comment: @FplNepal Did you enter it as array formula? This is important.

Comment: @JvdV I asked abput it in OP's question in the comments, and this was my understanding of the expectation.

Comment: Yes I did what you said me to do . 1st two row was okay. I was excited thinking finally it worked. But as mentioned it threw me ref error. Here is the link for the table ., Its in "calculation " sheet. Its editable. {https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GyEjrLKRAmNe3e8ipr-EEnJPPHWTLpEt/view}

Comment: @FplNepal I think you have the wrong formula inserted :) I uploaded a copy here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rzqeEgiSE3Nqm6NJmpg-YPzUlnMg-oAw

Comment: @Jerry Oh My god. You did it !! . This is exactly what I have asking for.. You saved mine lot of efforts and time. Thank you very very much. I am very thankful to you. :) . Thanx a lot.

Comment: @FplNepal どういたしまして :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest version of Excel, you can use `=MINIFS()` to find the first `Time` for that particular `Bill Number` (the `Checkin time`).

In cell `D3` enter this formula:

```
=MINIFS(B:B,E:E,E3)
```

Make sure that the cell has `Time` formatting for it to show correctly.

Comment: I tried with formula, it worked for 1st instance but not after the new bill number .

Comment: If you drag that formula down to where the new `Bill Number` starts in `D5` the formula should automatically increment to: `=MINIFS(B:B,E:E,E5)` - Is that what you're seeing in cell `D5`?

Comment: I also tried <code> =INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,E:E,0))
But as the bill number is repeated in same columns too , so it gives exact same time for every number repeated. 
Example I have bill Number 29 in E2 and E3 . Bill Number is also repeated at down rows like E104 and so on.... Once there is checkout from the customer , same number of bill receipt is issued everytime new order is taken.

Comment: Yes I can see the increment But the output doesnt for new bill

Comment: I'm not sure why the output wouldn't change if the `Bill Number` is different. When I'm using the formula in the spreadsheet I've replicated from your data, it works fine. Are you copying the formula exactly how I have explained above, or have you changed the ranges? Can you please edit your question to include what you have tried already, what output you are seeing and how it differs from what you expected?

Comment: Here is the link for  new screenshot. 
Here you can Till row 51 its okay. But row 52 have new bill number "5" which has time "18:38:01" But the formula getting it "17:40:50". 
Also At row 55 . There is new bill "1" . But its time is fetching from older "1" from above. 
Screenshot Link <https://ibb.co/g1v54T>

Comment: Are you saying `Bill Number` is not a unique key? So you will have more than one Bill where `Bill Number` = `1`?

Comment: Yes Bill Number is not unique. It is repeated many times . Yes I will have Bil number = 1 many times.

Comment: Why would does Table 33 have a Bill Number 1 at 16:00 and then at 18:40 table 33 has another Bill Number 1 (Which, I'm assuming from what you are saying is not the same customer)? Is there only ever one Bill Number for the day at each table? Currently the formula would get very complicated if you don't have a way to make use of a unique key. I'm assuming a combination of `Date`, `Table Number` and `Bill Number` would not make a unique record, would that be correct?

Comment: Bill Number depends upon how long customer stays . Suppose If X customers checks in and orders an item , that X bill number is created , lets say "1" . Then that bill numbers isnt created until X checks out. It will keep on producing new bill number but except "1" coz its still not checkout. As soon as X checksout, "1" bill number becomes available and goes on to serve for new customers "y" who enters and orders and item.

Comment: OK. And then how would you be able to tell that customer 'X' has checked out? If there was only one customer in the restaurant and they had `Bill Number` 1, then they checked out and then the next customer 'Y' who came got `Bill Number` 1, how would you know which items were purchased by customer 'X' and which were purchased by customer 'Y'?

Comment: The end of the bill number. point where new number is generated marks the end of the previous bill number. Hence we can figure out the customer checkout time.

Comment: You don't have customer checkout time on this spreadsheet. If you don't have a unique key, this formula will not work for you. If you do have a unique key, or if elements of your spreadsheet can be combined to make a unique key - please let me know.

Comment: No checkout time is not needed for the data. Only needed here is Check In time. and the way is as I mentioned on the post. yes the bill numbers arent unique. Isnt their a way to calculate by using minif and other formula to calculate unique ?

Comment: I can think of a way to do it using a dynamic range, `INDIRECT()` and possibly `MOD()` but it has come way too far out of scope of your original question to the point that it would need to be a completely new question. I would recommend you do some research on the formulas I've mentioned - If you do end up figuring out the answer, post it as an answer to your own question so it can help others in future.